# How to get helper function returning promise for React hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

I have the following React functional component with `useState` and `useEffect` hooks:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { requestInfo } from './helpers/helpers';

const App = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    requestInfo('people', '82')
      .then(results => setPeople(results))
  }, []);

  return (
    <p>We have {people.length} people in this game.</p>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In `helpers.js` I have this function:

```
export const requestInfo = (resource, quantity) => {
  fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/${resource}/?results=${quantity}`)
    .then(response => response.json)
    .then(data => data.results)
}
```

I don't have much experience of writing asynchronous functions that call APIs, but I've looked at other Q&As on this website that said in situations like this I need to have the helper function return a promise, then have the code that calls the helper function do something with the outcome of the promise, in this case pass it to the `setPeople` hook state setter function.

I'm currently getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` from within my call to `useEffect`.

I think the endpoint is correct because this command works and returns the expected data when run in my terminal:

```
curl https://swapi.dev/api/people/\?results\=82
```

I'd be very grateful if someone can show me how to modify one or both of my functions to make this work.

Comment: in requestInfo try `return fetch('https....` -- right now you're not returning anything from that function

Comment: I changed it to `return fetch(...` and the error message changed to: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` so something is still wrong.

Comment: response.json() in the requestInfo function -- i'd also log out the response and data variables in that function to see what I'm getting back.

Comment: Thanks I added the `()` on the end of `response.json`, but logging stuff to the console only gives me:  `Promise {<pending>}`, which is what I want, I think, as I'm meant to be returning a promise to get resolved by the code in the functional component.
Now getting three errors:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream is locked`
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'results' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a few issues - one in useEffect you need to await the response from the requestInfo call so:

```
useEffect(() => {
const getAsyncInfo = async () => {
  const res = await requestInfo('people', '82')
  setPeople(res)
}
getAsyncInfo()
}, [])
```

next make sure you are returning the fetch from `requestInfo` and it's `json()` as a function - requestInfo can use async/await as well such as:

```
export const requestInfo = async(resource, quantity) => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/${resource}/?results=${quantity}`)
  const json = await res.json()
  return json.results
}
```

Comment: Using async-await is completely optional and not needed in this case. The promise call is fine and can even be beneficial over the await in cases where you do multiple independent requests, because await is sequential (so it waits for one request to complete before it launches the other), whereas with `then` or `await Promise.all(...)` you can launch multiple fetch requests at the same time. That being said, await is usually preferred, but it does not solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `requestInfo` is currently not returning anything (hence the error message). You either need to get rid of the `{}` after the arrow, or you need to `return fetch(...).then(...)` etc.

```js
export const requestInfo = (resource, quantity) =>
  fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/${resource}/?results=${quantity}`)
    .then(response => response.json)
    .then(data => data.results)
```

```js
export const requestInfo = (resource, quantity) => {
  return fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/${resource}/?results=${quantity}`)
    .then(response => response.json)
    .then(data => data.results)
}
```